# Expected undefined to equal 'computers'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am learning ES 6 online and I have test:

> Implement the findLargestString function, which has a single argument
>   strings (an array of strings), which will set the largestString
>   variable defined at the top to the string which has the longest length
>   of the array of strings passed in as the strings parameter.

On start I have method:

```
let largestString;

function findLargestString(strings) {
    // set largestString to point to the 
    // longest string found in the strings array passed in
}
```

So I am tried:

```
let largestString;

function findLargestString(strings) {
    let largestString = '';
    strings.forEach((string) => {
        if (string.length > largestString.length) {
            largestString = string;
        }
    });

    return largestString;
}
```

But this return error:

```
largestString should be set to the largest string passed in

Expected undefined to equal 'computers'.
```

How can I make it?

Comment: You've re-declared `largestString` with `let` inside the function. Remove the `let` keyword from that line. Also, the `return` at the end is unnecessary.

Comment: i tried your code an i got no error , here's the [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aVEaxv?editors=1111)

Comment: "*Implement [a] function, which will set the `largestString` variable defined at the top…*" - Ouch. This is a horrible practice. You did the right thing and used a `return` value. Of course that doesn't work with the flawed test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine for me

```js
let largestString;

function findLargestString(strings) {
  let largestString = '';
  strings.forEach((string) => {
    if (string.length > largestString.length) {
      largestString = string;
    }
  });

  return largestString;
}

var arr = new Array('', 'aa', 'test')
console.log(findLargestString(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the return value of your function and take a look at how 'let' works

```
let largestString = findLargestString(strings);
```

Comment: The person is submitting the code to the online "grading" system. The system apparently expects the relatively-global `largestString` to be set as a side-effect of running the function.